# Java Prepared Statements Not Entirely Working - MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, prepared-statement

I am using Java Servlets to connect and insert data into my MYSQL database. I am currently using the following prepared statement:

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = ?;";
PreparedStatement stat1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
stat1.setString(1, username);
ResultSet result = stat1.executeQuery();
out.println("<h1> PREPARED STATEMENT WORKING </h1>");
```

Using this, the h1 header does not display.

However, I have got this to work:

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = \"" + username + "\";";
PreparedStatement stat1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
ResultSet result = stat1.executeQuery();

out.println("<h1> PREPARED STATEMENT WORKING </h1>");
```

Using this method, the h1 header is displayed. The question I have is, is the way I have managed to get working less secure? If so, how can I get the first method to work?

Comment: What happens with the first snippet? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Without seeing the exception, I can't know what's wrong with the first one.  The second one is definitely insecure.  Don't use it, or someone could cause you a lot of trouble by registering on your site with a username like 'joe"; drop table user'

Comment: Maybe it is just that I am more used to Oracle style, but I usually do not user quotes either for table names or column names, and not semicolon... maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: @Mureinik When it is run it displays a blank web page, with no exception displayed. If it makes any difference, the the variable 'username' is being retrieved from a html form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `;` from your queries and tell us if it's working or not.

Comment: This was the solution. Is this because executeQuery doesn't allow multiple queries?

Comment: It's  because SQL queries in MySQL doesn't use `;` in the end. Plesae also vote up :)

Comment: @hjalpmig MySQL does accept multiple SQL queries but you should pass an additional parameter to the connection URL when creating the connection.

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor any SQL statement use a semicolon in the end, but it's when it accepts multiple statements in the query. This isn't the case, thus the SQL Exception.